# PowerShell Wildcard

Tags: powershell, csv, replace

I want to replace anything in a *.csv* that is inside `()`.  I also want to replace the `()`.  Essentially I want to delete them, not replace.  But I am using replace, because I don't know what else to use.

Here is an example:

Here is what I have:

```
Sam Jones 2.432 GB (2,611,711,745 bytes)
Paul Jones 2.07 GB (2,223,079,317 bytes)
```

Here is what I want:

```
Sam Jones 2.432 GB
Paul Jones 2.07 GB
```

Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `-replace` operator with the appropriate regular expression:

```
# ~\> @("Sam Jones 2.432 GB (2,611,711,745 bytes)", "Paul Jones 2.07 GB (2,223,079,317 bytes)") -replace "\([^)]*\)",""
Sam Jones 2.432 GB 
Paul Jones 2.07 GB
```

Edit: Used Mike suggestion in comments for a more general purpose regular expression.

Comment: Worked like a champ @zdan -  Do you mind explaining what exactly `"\(.*\)"` does?

Comment: That regex might be problematic if you have multiple () on one line... e.g. it would turn "ABC (DEF) GHI (JKL)" into "ABC".  You might want to use `"\([^)]*\)"` instead if you have data like this.

Comment: @Mike I like that solution even better.